# CORS with Internet Explorer - support for basic authentication?

Tags: internet-explorer, basic-authentication, cors

When using CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) with Internet Explorer - does it support providing an Authroization (i.e. for basic Auth)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: no. Longer answer:

Internet Explorer 7 and below has no support for CORS

Internet Explorer 8 and 9 has limited CORS support via the XDomainRequest object. The XDomainRequest object does not support custom headers, therefore it can't support the `Authorization` header. (source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx)

The upcoming Internet Explorer 10 will have full support for CORS, which includes support for custom headers like `Authorization`. (source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/09/cors-for-xhr-in-ie10.aspx)

Comment: Ahh, Fantastic that's what I was looking to see is if there was light at the end of the tunnel (which there is, in the form of IE 10)

Comment: IE10 does not support basic authentication for images or media-files, linked in the `src` attribute when that points to a different URL. So far to IE10 and CORS ...

Answer (score 0):

Any public site that need to support IE7,8,9 withCredentials, DO NOT user CORS. Feature is disabled in internet zone "Access Data Sources Across Domains". Only trusted zone domains can make Cross domain calls.

Comment: Do you know of any documented evidence for this? Or is it just your personal findings?