# Backbone.js BasicAuth for IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, backbone.js, internet-explorer-9, cors

I am doing BasicAuth with Backbone.js. I have added this js file backbone.basicauth.js in order to be able to use the BasicAuth.

In Chrome, Firefox and Safari the call works fine, first Backbone is sending OPTIONS request method and then GET request method and I am getting the response that I need.

In IE 9 there is no OPTIONS request method and in the GET request method in the Request Heders there is no 'Authorization: Basic YUBtay5tazoxMjM='

I am using js libraries xdr.js and base64.js that should make it work in IE but with no result.

I know that there is not CORS support in IE 9 that is causing the problem.

The web application works fine in IE 10.

The API server is in php.

Had anyone had this kind of problem with IE?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be stuck. I haven't tried the plugin with IE9 but I'd fully expect it to fail: [CORS with Internet Explorer - support for basic authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468741/cors-with-internet-explorer-support-for-basic-authentication)